# Use Jquery to traverse up DOM to find input and modify value based on data- attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that has a price input which I would like to modify based on the options below it.

So when somebody clicks on `<a class="price_option" data-price="xxx" ... >` , the value of data-price will be entered to the respecting input field (`<input class="form-control price_dozen" ...`)

Below is the HTML code. Can somebody please help?

```html
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="price_dozen">Price (Dozen)</label>
        <div class="input-group  col-xs-7">
          <input class="form-control price_dozen" type="text" value="300">
          <div class="input-group-addon">/ lusin</div>
        </div>
        <a class="price_option" data-price="250" href="#">250</a> , <a  class="price_option" href="#">300</a> , <a href="#"  class="price_option">320</a>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="price_dozen">Price (Dozen)</label>
        <div class="input-group  col-xs-7">
          <input class="form-control price_dozen" type="text" value="300">
          <div class="input-group-addon">/ lusin</div>
        </div>
        <a class="price_option" data-price="250" href="#">250</a> , <a  class="price_option" href="#">300</a> , <a href="#"  class="price_option">320</a>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="price_dozen">Price (Dozen)</label>
        <div class="input-group  col-xs-7">
          <input class="form-control price_dozen" type="text" value="300">
          <div class="input-group-addon">/ lusin</div>
        </div>
        <a class="price_option" data-price="250" href="#">250</a> , <a  class="price_option" href="#">300</a> , <a href="#"  class="price_option">320</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: What do you have so far? The jQuery [documentation for traversing](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) is very complete, and the methods are very easy to understand and use.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(function(){
  $(".price_option").on("click",function(e){
    $(this).prev().find(".form-control").val($(this).attr("data-price"));
  });
});
```

But as suggested you should try out traversing on your own using pretty straightforward no-nonsense jquery methods.

PS : modify according to your specific requirement.

Comment: That works for the first link only.
So I used the code below:


    $(this).parent().find(".form-control").val($(this).attr("data-price"));